# Stereo audio processor: help with capacitors

Tags: capacitor, audio, through-hole

I'm building a small audio processor board that uses the [Silan Microelectronics SC7314](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.es/datasheet-pdf/view/301451/SILAN/SC7314S.html) and exclusively THT components. I've recycled this chip from a malfunctioning Philips Home theater.

The thing is that I don't have the unit anymore to see what capacitors were used, and the datasheet seems to be a little bit confusing. I'm having trouble with the different input capacitors. They say that 2.2 μF unpolarized capacitors should be used, and in my head I thought of disc ceramic capacitors. The thing is that when I went to my local electronic components store, they told me that they only had electrolytic capacitors of 2.2 μF, nothing on ceramic.

What other types of unpolarized capacitors are suitable for audio applications and are THT?

Answer (score 1):

For audio applications, you can use both electrolytic and ceramic capacitors can be used. (Regarding to the frequency response)

However, the problem comes with bias DC voltage.
When you're using electrolytic capacitor, need to care about direction.
The bias need to be in the same direction of electrolytic capacitor's polarity requirement.

On the page 11 of the SC73145 datasheet, there are several 2.2uF capacitors for various audio input channels.
**If you're not sure, just connect capacitor's + to the SC7314 side.**
As normal audio instruments like CD player or AM/FM tuner outputs non-biased audio signal, you can consider the input side as - compared to the IC's internal bias.

But the safest way is to find some ceramic capacitor with 1uF ~ 4.7uF capacity.

Answer (score 1):

The example schematics is just an example. It does not show much details about the circuit anyway, and as such, it should be taken more like a block diagtam.

So it does not mandate that the capacitors must be non-polarized. They can be, and in fact, since the chip has a single positive supply, the expectation is that the inputs have a positive bias anyway.

Electrolytic caps exist in polarized and non-polarized versions, and especially the non-polarized electrolytics are typically used in this kind of circuit.

Plastic caps are also non-polarized and suitable.

Ceramic capacitors are non-polarized, but depending on their material, they may not be that suitable for audio. You can still use them, SMD ceramics can rage from picofarads to tens of microfarads.

Answer (score 1):

Kigh-K ceramics like X7R, Y5V, etc are excellent for decoupling... but unsuitable for filtering and audio signal processing due to:

- High tolerance, high dependence on temperature, so you don't know where your filter critical frequencies will be
- Large capacitance dependence on voltage, which creates a correspondingly large amount of distortion
- Piezoelectric effect, which means they're pretty good microphones

On the other hand, C0G/NP0 ceramic caps have none of these drawbacks and are one of the lowest distortion caps, but they're only available in small values.

For the input and output coupling caps, since the chip is single supply, you can assume the pins will be biased around midsupply and use polarized electrolytic caps with the "+" towards the chip.

For the other, lower value caps used in the filters, it's best to use accurate caps so the left and right channel filters are well matched. Non-polarized electrolytics have high tolerance, but film/C0G caps are usually available in 5% or better, which will work well here.

The lowest distortion option is either C0G ceramic or MKP (polypropylene) film. Other types of film caps like MKT (mylar) may be cheaper, at the cost of a tiny increase of distortion that you won't notice anyway, so it's fine. If you go to a local electronics store, they'll probably have film caps in stock.